# Log4net ADONetAppender - View parameter values?

Tags: c#, log4net, adonetappender

Is it possible to view the AdoNetAppenderParameter values when debugging log4net?

If so, how?

Thanks!

Comment: FWIW, I've already enabled internal logging in log4net :)

Comment: Well, yes, if you run with the source code or debug symbols. Otherwise use the internal logging to log the values.

Comment: @stuartd, would you mind providing a quick example of how to add the values to the internal debugging, or perhaps point me to some reference?  My GoogleFu is failing me :(

Comment: you use the [`LogLog`](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/log4net-1.2.13/release/sdk/log4net.Util.LogLog.html) class.

Comment: I'm logging the threadcontext properties using LogLog, no problem, but I can't locate where the actual AdoNetAppenderParameter values are, in order to log them....

Comment: SQL profiling will show what the actual parameter values as sent to the server are, for anything else I think you'll need source/symbols.

Answer (score 0):

In the sourcecode from https://github.com/apache/log4net you will find the file AdoNetAppender.cs:

In the `virtual public void Prepare(IDbCommand command)` the parameters are assigned:

```
IDbDataParameter param = command.CreateParameter();

// Set the parameter properties
param.ParameterName = ParameterName;

    if (!m_inferType)
    {
        param.DbType = DbType;
    }
    if (Precision != 0)
    {
        param.Precision = Precision;
    }
    if (Scale != 0)
    {
        param.Scale = Scale;
    }
    if (Size != 0)
    {
        param.Size = Size;
    }

    // Add the parameter to the collection of params
    command.Parameters.Add(param);
```

When you debug that you can check the parameter-objects.